# Why does my code leak so much memory while running in a loop?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

Below is my function. It may loop 200000 times. While it is running, the memory is growing higher and higher, then it throws a memory error. Why did this happen, and how do I fix this bug?

Error info:

> error info:OpenCV(4.5.2)
> D:\MyMovieChannel\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:73: error:
> (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 5468160 bytes in function
> 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'

My code:

```
struct Similary
{
    Mat    frame;
    MatND  grayhist;
    MatND  rgbhist;
    string  phash;
    string  ahash;
    string  dhash;
};


void readFrames(const String& filename, vector<Similary>& vecframesims)
{
    Mat temframe;
    
    VideoCapture capture;
    Similary  framesims;
    if (capture.open(filename))
    {
        
        double videoFPS = capture.get(CAP_PROP_FPS);
        int nbFrames = capture.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
        //string = "begin road video frames, total frames is:"
        std::cout << "begin road video frames, total frames is : " << nbFrames << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i<nbFrames; i++)
        {
            capture >> framesims.frame;
            if (!framesims.frame.empty())
            {
                framesims.grayhist = GrayHistValue(framesims.frame);//funtion return a MatND value.
                framesims.rgbhist = HistValue(framesims.frame);//funtion return a MatND value.
                framesims.phash = pHashValue(framesims.frame);
                framesims.ahash = aHashValue(framesims.frame);
                framesims.dhash = dHashValue(framesims.frame);
                vecframesims.push_back(framesims);
            }
        }
        std::cout << "road video frames ended." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "video not ok" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{

    String  targetfile = "F:\\Movie\\01.mp4";
    vector<Similary>  vectargetframes;

    readFrames(targetfile, vectargetframes);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're storing all the frames in a vector. You can try `vecframesims.reserve(nbFrames);` before the "for i" loop, which might help, but with 5MB frames you can still run out of memory. You might need to read some frames, process them, then read some more.

Comment: Each iteration of the loop grows the vector that gets passed in as a parameter. Why do you expect this function ***not*** to continuously require more and more memory?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm perhaps you mean "*You might need to read some frames, process them, **clear them**, then read some more*"?